# using regex to apply filter and truncate data

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and trying to process text data from LDAP server. the text data has multiple records separated by ";" . I am trying to filter out the records based on some keyword. Then from the filtered records, extract the group name.

**Sample Data** : cn=ABC.DEVOPS.ADMIN,ou=securitygroups,o=lok; cn=BCD.DEVOPS.ADMIN,ou=securitygroups,o=lok; cn=DDI.OPERATEUR,ou=securitygroups,o=lok; cn=BYZ.LOKUS,ou=securitygroups,o=lok; cn=VB12312, ou=securitygroups, o=lok; cn=BYZ.MASTER,ou=securitygroups,o=lok;

From the above sample data I want to filter based on text "BYZ". this should return 2 records. cn=BYZ.LOKUS,ou=securitygroups,o=lok; cn=BYZ.MASTER,ou=securitygroups,o=lok;
And finally extract the group name out of it. It should return **LOKUS, MASTER**

Can you help me with the regex.

I am using apache httpd server to query the LDAP server. and using following code to set response header
 **RequestHeader edit* X-Remote-Groups regex-to-be-do**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `BYZ[.](.+),`

1. match the sequence `BYZ`
2. match the literal "." by enclosing in square brackets `[.]`, because "." is a special character in regex language that means "any character". Items in square brackets are treated as literal characters even if they normally have special meanings.
3. capture in a group everything that follows until the comma: `(.+?),`. The ? causes the .+ to only capture as few characters as needed to meet the requirements. Otherwise the entire rest of the data is captured.

You can play around with this regex [on Pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=BYZ%5B.%5D(.%2B%3F)%2C&test_string=cn%3DABC.DEVOPS.ADMIN%2Cou%3Dsecuritygroups%2Co%3Dlok%3B%20cn%3DBCD.DEVOPS.ADMIN%2Cou%3Dsecuritygroups%2Co%3Dlok%3B%20cn%3DDDI.OPERATEUR%2Cou%3Dsecuritygroups%2Co%3Dlok%3B%20cn%3DBYZ.LOKUS%2Cou%3Dsecuritygroups%2Co%3Dlok%3B%20cn%3DVB12312%2C%20ou%3Dsecuritygroups%2C%20o%3Dlok%3B%20cn%3DBYZ.MASTER%2Cou%3Dsecuritygroups%2Co%3Dlok%3B&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

The result will be two matches each with one group, `LOKUS`, and `MASTER`

Comment: amazing, how to use this in apache httpd conf file to extract the user group.